# Angular UI Bootstrap monthpicker

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to setup the date picker to work as a month picker. Everything works as expected as long as you're clicking a month and/or going to prev/next year. However, if you want to broaden the year selection by clicking the current year from the top, I get a JavaScript error.

HTML:

```html
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="TestController">
        <input type="date" class="form-control" ng-model="date" datepicker-popup="MM/yyyy" is_open="date_opened" ng-focus="date_opened = true" ng-click="date_opened = true" datepicker-options="datepickerOptions">
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```js
(function() {
    'use strict';

    var app  = angular.module('app', [
        'ui.bootstrap'
    ]);

    app.controller('TestController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.datepickerOptions = {
            datepickerMode: "'month'",
            minMode: 'month'
        };
    }]);
})();
```

Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o1mLa6Lr/2/) demonstrating it (angularjs 1.2.26, ui-bootstrap 0.11.2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out you need to explicitly define the datepicker mode in the controller:

```
$scope.datepickerMode = 'month';
```

and then use it as an attribute:

```
datepicker-mode="datepickerMode"
```

Answer (score 2):

Make the following changes as highlighted in comments:

```
 (function() {
'use strict';

var app  = angular.module('app', [
    'ui.bootstrap'
]);

app.controller('TestController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.datepickerOptions = {
        datepickerMode: "month",     // Remove Single quotes
        minMode: 'month'
    };
}]);
```

})();

Comment: can u please explain what breaks in this case??

Comment: Datepicker opens in day mode, try it in the fiddle. Thanks!